# How do I convert integers to characters in C#?

Tags: c#, char

I am trying to convert an index of 1 to 27 into the corresponding uppercase letter. I know that in C++ I could type this:

```
char letter = 'A' + (char)(myIndex % 27);
```

This same code does not work in C#. How can I accomplish this task in C#?

EDIT: I'd rather not have to encode an enum or switch statement for this if there is a better mathematical solution like the one above.

Comment: char letter = Convert.ToChar(myIndex);

Comment: char letter = Convert.ToChar(myIndex+64);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you add (or subtract) two characters, you get an Int32 in C#.  This will work:

```
int letter = 'A' + (char)(myIndex % 27);
```

If you want a char, you need to explicitly cast it again:

```
char letter = (char) ('A' + (char)(myIndex % 27));
```

However, this most likely should actually be:

```
char letter = (char) ('A' + (char)((myIndex - 1) % 26));
```

Comment: Yes. Even better would be s/myIndex/(myIndex - 1)/ :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a table driven solution:

```
char ToUpperChar(int index)
{
    if (index < 1 || index > 26)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

    return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[index-1]; // took out the % - it's range-checked above.
}
```

Comment: +1 for a more original approach. so many type-castings were getting boring ;) And it's purely mathematical since array indexing is syntax sugar for pointer arithmetics.

Answer (score 4):

```
char letter = (char)('A' + (myIndex-1)%26);
```

(edit out magic number, adjusted indices)

Comment: Oh, right. '%26'. Thanks. I guess I was making that one harder than it needed to be.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you'll have to do your casting slightly differently:

```
char letter = (char)('A' + (myIndex % 27));
```

However, your math might also be wrong, and this is probably closer to what you actually want:

```
char letter = (char)('A' + ((myIndex - 1) % 26));
```

Comment: %27 is wrong, should be 26 :-) There are only 26 letters in Latin alphabet.

Comment: I kind of copied that from the original code... he says he has an index from 1 to 27 anyways. Of course, to get the correct latin letter he should do ('A' + (char)((myIndex - 1) % 26))

Comment: Because I'm not quite sure what OP wants exactly. At least this solves the problem with casting.

Answer (score 1):

How about an extension method?

```
    public static int Index(this char letter)
    {
        const int offset = 64;
        if(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')
            return (Convert.ToInt32(letter) - offset);
        return 0;
    }
```

//usage...
char letter = 'A';
int index = letter.Index();

Comment: Sorry! Wrong way. Try this...
 
public static char CharToIndex(this int number) { 
  const int offset = 64; 
  if ( number >= 1 && number <= 26) 
    return (Convert.ToChar(number + offset)); 
  return '\0'; 
}
 
// Usage ... 
int i=1; 
char c = i.CharToIndex();

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
byte upperA = 65;
byte index = 1;

char letter = (char)(upperA + (index % 27));

Console.WriteLine(letter);
```

I also like Reed's answer.